# RetroLamba not working with android studio

Tags: android, java-8, retrolambda

I have added retrolambda to my android project but when I try to run the project it shows the following error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileRetrolambdaDebug'.
>   A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\bin\java.exe''

I have added the library as following

in build.gradle (project file) under dependencies

```
classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'
classpath 'me.tatarka.retrolambda.projectlombok:lombok.ast:0.2.3.a2'
```

in build.gradle (app module) file I have applied it as plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

project build without error but when I try to run it, it shows the above error. what can be the issue here?

Comment: switch to AS3.0.0 it supports some java8 features - its gonna be very soon in dev channel

Comment: need this workin now, any other options

Comment: it is working now, but in [canary channel](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-30-canary-1-sdk-updates.html)

Comment: ok thanks, let me try it.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html

Answer (score 2):

I use retrolambda in AndroidStudio 2.2.3.

My app build.gradle

```
....
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

....
...
```

My project build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0'

}
```